# Not able to access data from CDH 5.1 Hive using SpagoBI tool

Tags: hadoop, jar, hive, spagobi

I am using SpagoBI tool to create report. I was able to ping successfully to `"CDH 5.1 Hive" using the driver:"org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver".`

But i am not able to access data using dataset in SpagoBI server.The url format is:`"jdbc:hive2://***.***.*.**:10000/default.`

The different drivers that i put in the lib folders are:

```
commons-cli-1.2.jar,
commons-collections-3.2.1-1.0.0.jar, 
commons-configuration-1.7.jar, 
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar, 
guava-11.0.2.jar, 
hadoop-0.21.0-thriftfs.jar, 
hadoop-auth-0.23.6.jar, 
hadoop-common-0.21.0.jar, 
hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar, 
hadoop-hdfs-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0.jar, 
hive-common-1.1.0.jar, 
hive-exec-0.11.0.jar, 
hive-jdbc-0.11.0.jar, 
HiveJDBC41.jar, 
hive-metastore-0.11.0.jar, 
hive-service-0.11.0.jar, 
httpclient-4.5.jar, 
httpclient-cache-4.5.jar, 
httpclient-win-4.5.jar, 
httpcore-4.4.1.jar, 
httpmime-4.5.jar, 
libfb303-0.9.0.jar, 
libthrift-0.9.0.jar, 
log4j-1.2.14.jar, 
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar, 
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar, 
TCLIServiceClient.jar, 
zookeeper-3.4.6.jar.
```

Please help me.

Comment: After hell out of google search i found out that we need to add the location of all jar files to (location/*.jar)CLASSPATH. There may be problem with some formats like i had problem with Date column, that's why i was not able to access data. When i excluded date column and queried for other columns, i got the data.

Answer (score 0):

Please, Paste Below Mentioned Drivers to SpagoBi-Server/lib Directory

1. hadoop-common-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041.jar
2. z-hive-jdbc-0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041-standalone.jar

Definitely, it will work.